# Unable to systrace on HTC One M8 Lollipop

Tags: android, systrace

I am trying to use *systrace* from Android Studio with the default *systrace* options set. I have not rooted the phone. HTC Sense v6.0, Android 5.0.1, HTC SDK API level 6.55. When I do so, I get the dreaded "Unable to collect system trace. Reason: unexpected error while collecting system trace". Using ADB shell, I have determined that /sys/kernel/debug exists, but /sys/kernel/debug/tracing does not.

Anyone else has better luck with *systrace* and HTC One M8 / Lollipop?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also see https://www.gamebench.net/en/blog/youve-heard-benchmark-cheating-what-about-benchmark-avoidance which claims that this is intentional on HTC's part. I've upgraded to Marshmallow.